# Pathauto , Using Body Value for URL Alias

Tags: path-aliases

I am trying to use the use the node body value for URL alias using Pathauto . I am trying the below path pattern : content/[node:body:?]
But this doesn't seem to have any effect . 
I have tried this also : content/[node:body:Text] ..yet no result .

Any pointers to resolve this is highly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without questioning why you would want body text in a URL alias you should be able to access this by using:

```
[node:body:value] for the value
[node:body:summary] for the summary
```

Comment: Hi , I tried [node:body:value] still does'nt create alias. My  node title doesnt have relevant information ..it has numbers. So , I am tryin g to get body value for alias.